# Potential risks when sending plain text E-Mails with encrypted attachments?

Tags: encryption, email

To ensure privacy in communication I encrypt and sign E-Mails using gpg4win. However, sometimes the communication does not work as expeceted (GPGTools and Outlook/gpg4win seem to be incompatible).

In such cases I ask the counterparty to send an encrypted attachment. I decrypt it, then write my answer into the file, encrypt it and send it back. The E-Mails are always plain text, but the attachments are always encrypted.

Is my approach, except for usability, a viable option?

Comment: Are you using the same algo's for both scenarios?

Comment: Good question, have to check. But since I don't change defaults, I assume it's the same.

Answer (score 1):

If the underlying algo's and methods (i.e. including signing) are the same then the reliance on the actual encryption is no different and in the real-world there is little difference in risk.

From a theoretical cryptanalysis standpoint one could argue that if the plaintext covering email provided context it would aid an attack on the cipher text, but modern algo's make this largely irrelevant.
One could also argue that if the entire email is encrypted an attacker would not know which aspect of the cipher text is email and which is attachment, but again if the crypto is reliable this is really only a theoretical difference in security. And provided the attachment is signed an attacker will not be able to replace the attachment (without the recipient being aware).

From a practical perspective I have always relied on specifically encrypted attachments rather than rely on a built-in email client mechanism, this is so that I know before an attachment is used that it has been encrypted and therefore no matter what finger trouble I have, when creating and sending the email, the attachment will always be encrypted and only accessible to the intended recipients (which in my opinion outweighs any theoretical benefits of encrypting the whole email).

Answer (score 1):

Encrypted emails are also plain text. This might sound like a paradox, but its not. When you encrypt a email message, the email body is replaced by the encrypted ASCII-armoured text, which is a simple BASE64-representation of the original encrypted data. Attachments are also plain text, all attachments are converted to BASE64 Before put in the email message. If you encrypt the attachment prior to sending it, it will be encrypted, then BASE64 converted, then BASE64 converted again (thus double-BASE64ing it) when you attach it to email. (if the PGP application ASCII armours encrypted files).

Thus, your scenario is as safe as Writing the message directly in the email and encrypting the email.

Answer (score 0):

Some companies refuse to permit PGP or s/MIME encrypted emails into their environment, because encrypted attachments can't be scanned for viruses/spam, etc.

This is a part of defense in depth, and usually includes

1. MTA scanning  (MSFT hosted forefront, Symantec, Proofpoint, etc)
2. Server scanning (Trend Micro for Exchange, ?? for Lotus Notes...)
3. Desktop Scanning (AVG, Trend, McAfee, ..)

To make things worse, most phones don't have AV software on them, and encrypted emails may sneak past the first two layers and allow an unsuspecting end user to install adware, or be redirected to a malicious HTTP/s site.